# Removing marker by latitude/longitude in google maps

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have set of markers in my google map. And at the right side of my map I have list of places marked in the map. Now upon clicking the places the color of the pin/marker should be changed. For this I thought I would delete the marker with latitude and longitude(which I will get on clicking the places link) and place a new marker with new image. But I dont know how to delete a marker with latitude and longitude or by place. Please help.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = null;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function createMarker(place) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });

        var address = place.formatted_address;



        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setTitle(address);
        marker.setVisible(true);
        address = address + '<a href="#" class="link" title="Been there" alt="' + address + '">B</a>&nbsp;<a class="link" href="#" title="Want to go" alt="' + address + '">W</a>&nbsp;<a class="link" href="#" alt="' + address + '" title="Favourite">F</a>';
        $('#trip_location').append(address);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.title + '</strong><br>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
    }



    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);
        var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            input.className = '';
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                input.className = 'notfound';
                return;
            }
            var location = place.geometry.location;
            var address = place.formatted_address;
            createMarker(place);
        });
    }

    $('#trip_location').on('click', '.link', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var location = $(this).attr('alt');
    });


    $('.clear').click(function() {
        $('#searchTextField').val('');
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

I will be adding multiple markers to google map through google's autocomplete. And the places of the markers will be listed on the right side of the page. When the user clicks the places, it should replace the marker icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting and replacing, you could keep a reference to each marker that is associated with a place and just call `setIcon` on it passing the new setting. See documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

EDIT: New code in question.

Added markers array to contain the markers, used data attribute to hold marker id, pull markerid attribute value when link element click event is fired.

NOTE: Not tested, so it may be buggy.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = null;
    var markers = [];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function createMarker(place) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });

        var address = place.formatted_address;



        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setTitle(address);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        markers.push(marker);
        address = address + '<a href="#" class="link" title="Been there" alt="' + address + '" data-markerid='" + (markers.length - 1) + "'>B</a>&nbsp;<a class="link" href="#" title="Want to go" alt="' + address + '">W</a>&nbsp;<a class="link" href="#" alt="' + address + '" title="Favourite" data-markerid='" + (markers.length - 1) + "'>F</a>';


        $('#trip_location').append(address);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.title + '</strong><br>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
    }



    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);
        var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            input.className = '';
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                input.className = 'notfound';
                return;
            }
            var location = place.geometry.location;
            var address = place.formatted_address;
            createMarker(place);
        });
    }

    $('#trip_location').on('click', '.link', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var location = $(this).attr('alt');
        var markerid = $(this).data('markerid');
        var marker = markers[markerid];
    });


    $('.clear').click(function() {
        $('#searchTextField').val('');
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Comment: But onclicking the places I will be getting only latitude & longitude of a marker in the map. How to change the icon image with that latitude and longitude?

Comment: lat and long are the only thing you need to plot a map. after you remove the previous marker, call the Marker() again with the lat, long and with a new image i.e pink image in ur case.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're building your page, might need more code. A suggestion might be to store an array of lat/lngs that is associated with each marker and traverse that to find the appropriate marker. Alternatively as you build the places UI you could pass the marker id instead.

Comment: @sandeep I'm saying that I dont know how to remove the marker with lat and long, and you are telling me to remove it and add new image?

Comment: Just store the markers in a global array while creating. Then use this code to remove. markers_array[index].setMap(null); However you have to get the exact index of the marker which you want to remove. That you can get in the reverse way, like when you click on the outside list of a place, get the lat/long., from that get the array index.

Comment: I have added my code. There is a problem. Since I need to create multiple markers, I coded that inside a function called createmarker. Now scope of the marker is only within that function.

Comment: @Jonathan I have added my code. Is there anything that you could do?

Comment: @JoshuaShrav updated my answer to contain some tweaked code that may help